# How can I write this sql query in django orm?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a sql query that works like this, but I couldn't figure out how to write this query in django. Can you help me ?

```
select datetime,
       array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object(parameter, raw)))  as parameters
  from dbp_istasyondata
 group by 1
 order by 1;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `raw` function of django orm. You can write your query like this:

```
YourModel.objects.raw('select * from your table'): #---> Change the model name and query
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have PostgreSQL system functions. Django ORM doesn't have all these functions. Django ORM can cover it partially.

Now you can do one of these.

1. Write ''raw sql'' and execute it.
2. You can write python @staticmethods to implement that functionality then use it in your view.py. (Here you'll have python-power)